# Change Type Hint of Inherited Method

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

### Problem

Suppose you have a class `A` and a subclass `B`. If `A` has the method `foo` which returns a different variable type than `B`, how would you override the method's type hint without re-defining/overriding the method itself?

### Realistic Example

```py
class RGB:
    def __init__(self, color: Union[tuple[int, int, int], tuple[int, int, int, int]]) -> None:
        self.__color: Union[tuple[int, int, int], tuple[int, int, int, int]] = color
        return

    def __eq__(self, other: Union[RGB, RGBA]) -> bool:
        return isinstance(other, RGB) and self.__color == other.color

    @property
    def color(self) -> tuple[int, int, int]:
        return self.__color


class RGBA(RGB):
    def __init__(self, color: tuple[int, int, int, int]) -> None:
        super().__init__(color)
        return

    @property
    def color(self) -> tuple[int, int, int, int]:
        return self.__color
```

As you can see, the `color` attribute varies based on whether the given color has an alpha value or not. But I do not want/need to redefine/override the `color` property method, the functionality does not change. How would I define the return type hint for the `color` property without overriding the method?

Ideally, the `RGBA` class would just contain the `__init__` function.

Comment: This breaks the Liskov Substitution Principle; you shouldn't be changing type of  `color` at all. An RGBA specification isn't a kind of RGB specification. Don't use inheritance.

Comment: I have never heard of this principle, thank you for the information.

Comment: I would use two separate classes. It's tempting to *reverse* the inheritance, letting an RGB specification be a special kind of RGBA spec that always sets the alpha channel to 0 or `None` or some other fixed value, but even that's sketchy. Conversion from RGBA to RGB is straightforward (drop the alpha channel), but the reverse direction requires you to specify an arbitrary alpha value.

Comment: I think there is a valid case different from this example that doesn't violate inheritance principles: when the return type of the subclass method is itself a subclass of the parent class method. I.e. `A.foo()` returns type `C` and `B.foo()` returns type `D` and `D ` is a subclass of `C`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a generic `Color` class that serves as the common parent of both `RGB` and `RGBA`, parameterized by the tuple type used to represent each. For example,

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


C = TypeVar('C')


class Color(Generic[C]):
    def __init__(self, c: C):
        self.__color = c

    @property
    def color(self) -> C:
        return self.__color


class RGB(Color[tuple[int,int,int]]):
    pass


class RGBA(Color[tuple[int,int,int,int]]):
    pass
```

This is just a start; you may run into other problems as you add more details to the classes.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, this would set this `TypeVar`, `C`, to the desired `tuple` for the individual RGB-like classes?

Comment: Correct. If nothing else, this at least makes the subclasses independent of each other, simplifying each of their definitions without having to worry about the other(s).

Comment: That is fascinating. My IDE, unfortunately, does not seem to comprehend deeper than the `TypeVar`, `C`, but this answer makes logical sense, thank you!